# How can i add Procedures to Python MySql method?

Tags: python, sql

So the procedure does work in SQL. It looks something like this. Kinda proud of it sniff

```
USE varehusdb;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Kundeinfo()
BEGIN
    SELECT vare.VNr, vare.Betegnelse, kunde.Fornavn, kunde.Etternavn, kunde.Adresse, kunde.PostNr, ordrelinje.OrdreNr, ordrelinje.PrisPrEnhet, ordrelinje.PrisPrEnhet * ordrelinje.Antall AS TotalPris
    FROM vare JOIN ordrelinje 
    ON vare.VNr = ordrelinje.VNr
    JOIN ordre
    ON ordrelinje.OrdreNr = ordre.OrdreNr
    JOIN kunde
    ON ordre.KNr = kunde.KNr
    ORDER BY vare.Betegnelse;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Though if someone can tell me what Group means then i would appreciate it too.

But my main problem is, i have no idea on how to properly make it print it out in Python.
I have this code in Python

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

host = 'localhost'
user = 'root'
password = 'root'
database = 'varehusdb'

try:
    connection=mysql.connector.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password,database=database)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("Kundeinfo")
    for result in cursor.stored_results:
        print(result.fetchall())
    print("Stored Procedure is executed")
except Error as e:
    print ("Error occured ",e)
```

Kundeinfo is the one i want to call. But it always gives me this error message called ( line 14, in 
for result in cursor.stored_results:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable )

I wonder what code in Python would actually be useful?

Comment: `cursor.stored_results` -> `cursor.stored_results()`

Comment: Gracias my man!!!!